# Remove Mass action from Sales/Order Grid

Tags: sales, sales-order, extensions, massaction, delete

I need to remove a few options from the Admin/Sales/Order Actions list. I do not want to edit the core files in Magento

Right now when I click on the drop down list Actions in the top right corner of the page, it shows Print Invoices among other things. I want to remove that option in my code without editing anything in the core files.

I know currently if I delete the following line of code from Core file Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php the option will not be displayed.

```
$this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfinvoices_order', array(
         'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Invoices'),
         'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfinvoices'),
    ));
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the massaction block has a name, if this is the case you can add `<remove name="nameOfBlock">` to a local.xml you add to the adminhtml theme.

If the block is anonymous, which I guess, you can implement an observer listening on the event `core_block_abstract_to_html_before`, check for the instance of the block, make sure you handle the right block and then `setTemplate('')`. Due to the check in `_toHtml()` this returns nothing